# Icons for cell padding adjustments

Tags: icon, interface-design, google-material-design

I am at a dead end right now, with 2 icons.   I have a table, above the table I have 2 icons, the 2 icons will be buttons that will change the padding of the table cells.

Just like in gmail, you are able to change the table cell padding.  To cozy, compact, etc...

But in my table, I just need to, 'comfortable' and 'compact'.

This is what the UI looks like now.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

It just doesn't look good...

I just need to get 2 good icons, I dont want to use text.

Also I reference Google material design, but I can't find an icon on there icon library that fits my situation.

Comment: I don't see any problem with those icons.

Comment: What exactly is not good? "doesn't look good" is very subjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can keep your two icons and they will look much cleaner once you remove the arrows. You could also try using a color other than green, a lot of people (myself included) find green hard to look at. [image]

There is also the possibility of a treatment that doesn't involve two icons, only one that serves as an affordance for a menu that lets users toggle. This gives you flexibility to add a third or fourth option if you wanted. *And* you can use the chunkier of the two icons. I think one of the things going on is that the 'compact' icon in your example is hard to look at on a screen because the lines are so close together.

[image]